# Why is DSolve different when the equation is built programmatically?

Tags: differential-equations, variable

Here is a simple differential equation.

```
mwe=y[x]/.First@DSolve [{y'[x]==x-2*x*y[x],y[0]==0},y[x],x]
```

I get the answer $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2}$

If I build up the same equation in a simple program, I get a different answer:

```
lsolve[r_,q_,a_,eta_]=y[x]/.First@DSolve[{y'[x]==r-q*y[x],y[a]==eta},y[x],x];
nwe=lsolve[x,2*x,0,0]
```

After simplifying, I get the answer $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{e^{-2x^2}}{2}$. Where did the extra factor of $2$ in the exponent come from? And how can I make it go away?

Comment: Here are the docs on this issue, in case it helps someone else. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You attempt to solve the ODE at the time of definition of `lsolve`. At this point, `q` does not depend on `x`. You really want to use `SetDelayed` here:

```
lsolve[r_, q_, a_, eta_] := 
  y[x] /. First@DSolve[{y'[x] == r - q*y[x], y[a] == eta}, y[x], x];
nwe = lsolve[x, 2*x, 0, 0] // Simplify
```

> 1/2 - E^-x^2/2

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I asked. Even though my version was syntactically correct, it would have been nice if Mathematica produced a warning!

Comment: How should Mathematica be able to detect that this does not align with your expectations? Both syntaxes `f[x_] = ...` and `f[x_] := ...` have the applications, e.g., the former can be considered as a shorthand for `f[x_] := Evaluate[...]`. This is usefull whenever a symbolic compuation can already performed at the time of definition so that it need not be redone every time `f` is called.

Comment: As you said in the answer: "At this point, `q` does not depend on `x`."  I think Mathematica should be able to tell that I was building an expression that does depend on `x` and then generate a warning (but certainly not an error) very much along the lines of what you told me.  Otherwise everyone who doesn't know about `:=` will end up asking a question similar to mine.  How to preempt that and automate your answer? :-)

Comment: When an assignment is made with `=`, `Mathematica` can only set the left hand side to the value of the right hand side _at the time of assignment_. Evaluate `y[x]/.First@DSolve[{y'[x]==r-q*y[x],y[a]==eta},y[x],x]` (just in case: in a fresh kernel) and you will see that the result is `(E^(-q x) (E^(a q) eta q - E^(a q) r + E^(q x) r))/q`. Because _Mathematica_ solves the ODE at this point in time and because `q` is independent of `x`. Of course, you may tell _Mathematica_ that `q` should depend on `x` by using `q[x]` instead of `q`, but I don't think you will like the result either.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "automation". The difference between `=` and `:=` lies in the time of execution of the right hand side. If you want that the ODE is solved only after a precise value of `q` is supplied, you _have_ to use `:=`. And yes, there are **a lot** of questions on the subtle differences of `=` and `:=` on this site. And I have to admit that was also something that was quite miraculous to me when I started to use the language. It helps a bit to recall that _Mathematica_, in its core, is nothing else but a term rewriting system.

Comment: OK, I see better how to phrase my "feature request".  The warning should be emitted when `lsolve` is called, since it is only then that it would be clear to the machine that `q`, or more precisely, `q_`, depends on `x`.  The warning message would something like: "It looks like you are calling a precompiled function with a dependent variable that is ignored, if you did not want that behaviour, use `:=` when you define the function."

Comment: You know, _Mathematica_ is not a mind-reading tool. Tell me, how should _Mathematica_ tell that calling `lsolve` with an `x`-dependent `q` should be potentially harmful? The best she can do is **to do precisely what you asked her to do**.

Comment: Several programming languages give a warning when `=` is used instead of `==` or vice versa, even though both usages may be syntactically valid.  Mathematica itself gives [warnings](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WarningsAndMessages.html) on a routine basis: "if it looks as if the Wolfram Language is doing something you definitely did not intend, Wolfram Language will usually print a message to warn you." In the current case is a matter of keeping track of free and bound variables. **However, this comment field is not big enough to contain the full solution to the problem.**